# How do you say "X is my only friend"?

Tags: значения, одним-словом

How do you say "X is my only friend" in Russian?

For example:

> Alcohol is my only friend.

Google translate uses the word `единственные,` but when I try to find example sentences containing this word, I don't get many results, so I'm suspicious about whether this word is right or not.

Comment: Google is right. "Алкоголь мой единственный друг".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We say it like this: «имя» - мой единственный друг.

Or if it's a female: «имя» - моя единственная подруга.

In reference to a person of course. But you're talking about alcohol here, so just take my first example and put the word алкоголь at the beginning!

Answer (score 2):

It's OK to say

Алкоголь — мой единственный друг.

Or Мой единственный друг — алкоголь.

Another less formal variant would be:

У меня только один друг — алкоголь. Or У меня нет друзей, кроме бутылки.

It'd be better for you to use бутылка or водка instead of the more general word, алкоголь, which sounds formal.
But you'd be better off just finding a different friend (just kidding).

Comment: for a t-shirt design with cats on it, I will give a name to this t-shirt how would you say "cats are my only friends" ?

Comment: Кошки— мои единственные друзья.

Comment: If I were you I would write," there's no better friend than a cat" Лучше кошки друга нет.

Comment: yes that is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Алкоголь — мой единственный друг.
Мой единственный друг - алкоголь.
Друг мой единственный - алкоголь.
Алкоголь - друг мой единственный.
// my only - мой единственный
Все формы уместны, но в разном контексте.